# Handling sql errors (if exists, if constraint), Perl

Tags: mysql, sql, perl

I am using perl and mysql on my site.

Is there a mechanism to restrict deleting if data connected to 'deleting' exists? Yes - foreign key constraint. Is it possible to return some code if row wasn't deleted because of foreign key constraint? Somethink like this:

```
$id = $cgi->param("id");                          
$query="delete from `Class` where `id` = '$id'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($query);
$sth->execute or die(print $sth->errstr);
if ($sth->errcode eq '777') 
{
    print 'error! there are 1 or more rows, connected with row you want to delete';
}
else
{
    print 'ok! deleted';
}
```

Same for inserting row and there are row with same data existing. Sure It is possible to create trigger on insert and try to return some code. Give me example of such trigger, please? And again : how to handle this error?

Some help please! Sorry for my not very good english :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to return your own success/failure code then you can use procedures. create a procedure

```
delimiter $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `deleteProcedure`(in Id INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN
            select 0; -- number that you want to return on failure
            ROLLBACK;
    END;

START TRANSACTION;
    -- put any number of statement, including delete, insert, update
    delete from `Class` where `id` = Id;
COMMIT;
         select 1; -- number that you want to return on success
END$$
```

call this procedure from your perl script, and it will return the values you put in your procedure.